# Line of dots in a Section with Text at the end

Tags: formatting, sections-paragraphs

I'm having a section in which i need to append dotted line till the line end. At the end i need some text.

Exactly like the below

> Healthcare
>   Management..................................................................................
>   ORACLE
>   Healthcare
>   Management..................................................................................
>   MICROSOFT

Researched on this topic. Couldn't find any solution

Any help.??

Comment: `A\dotfill B` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Provided a loose usage of the word *exactly* :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \begin{document}
        Healthcare Management \dotfill ORACLE \\
        Healthcare Management \dotfill MICROSOFT
    \end{document}
```

[image]

should do the trick.

For the white space at the end of `MICROSOFT` I suppose you could use `\hspace{10cm}`.